# In WPF and MVVM, how to add a "Copy" context menu to a <Hyperlink>?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, mvvm-light

In most web modern browsers, one can right click on a hyperlink and use the "Copy link address ..." context menu.

In WPF, I'm wondering if there is a method to add the same functionality to the `<Hyperlink>` XAML tag?

I'm using MVVM Light.

Comment: Sure.  Add a context menu to it.  Come back and [edit] if you have problems with doing that.

Comment: See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/162784/WPF-ContextMenu-Strikes-Again-DataContext-Not-Upda

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually more difficult than it should be.

The reason is that [ContextMenu is not part of the visual tree](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/162784/WPF-ContextMenu-Strikes-Again-DataContext-Not-Upda), which means that attempting to use any of the most logical bindings returns null instead of the expected value.

The solution is to wrap the entire Hyperlink in a UserControl, then use `{Binding PlacementTarget.Content}` to access the properties we want. In this case, the required property is the URL, which we need for the parameter when we want to copy the hyperlink to the clipboard via the context menu. Of course, we could specify the URL twice, but that violates the DRY (Dont Repeat Yourself) principle.

I'm using [MVVM Light](https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/).

### XAML

The intent of the second `Command Parameter` is to bind to the contents of `NavigateUri` in the parent `Hyperlink` tag, and pass that in as a parameter for the context menu, so it can be copied onto the clipboard.

```
<UserControl>
    <Hyperlink NavigateUri="http://www.google.com/" 
               Command="{Binding OnClickHyperlink}"
               CommandParameter="{Binding NavigateUri, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
        www.google.com
        <Hyperlink.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="Copy link address" 
                          Command="{Binding OnCopyHyperlink}"                                                  
                          CommandParameter="{Binding PlacementTarget.Content.NavigateUri, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContextMenu}}">
                </MenuItem>
            </ContextMenu>
        </Hyperlink.ContextMenu>
    </Hyperlink>
</UserControl>
```

### C# for Hyperlink Click

```
private ICommand _onClickHyperlink;
public ICommand OnClickHyperlink
{
    get
    {
        return _onClickHyperlink ?? (_onClickHyperlink = new RelayCommand<Uri>(
            hyperlink =>
            {
                // Handle Hyperlink click here using Process.Start().
            }));
    }
}
```

### C# for Hyperlink Copy

```
private ICommand _onCopyHyperlink;
public ICommand OnCopyHyperlink
{
    get
    {
        return _onCopyHyperlink ?? (_onCopyHyperlink = new RelayCommand<Uri>(
            hyperlink =>
            {
                Clipboard.SetText(hyperlink.OriginalString);
            }));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the following approach useful when creating a custom log window control. It checks to see if the mouse is currently hovering over a text run inside a hyperlink object.

```
private void LogWindow_ContextMenuOpening(object sender, ContextMenuEventArgs e)
{
   var hyperlink = (Mouse.DirectlyOver as Run)?.Parent as Hyperlink;
   if(hyperlink != null)
   {
       //do whatever you want with the link now
       //e.g. set the command param on a named menu item  
       MenuItem item = this.UriCopyMenuItem;
       item.CommandParameter = hyperlink.NavigateUri;
       item.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
       ...
    }
}
```